# Prevent Json.NET 4.5 from appending timezone offset when using MicrosoftDateFormat

Tags: json.net

Short of a custom `DateTimeConverterBase` implementation, is there some way to keep Json.NET 4.5+, when set to use `DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat`, from appending a timezone offset for any non-UTC `DateTime` it is given?

```
"\/Date(1333645844276-0600)\/"
```

### Details

I am switching an API project from using the built-in .NET `JavaScriptSerializer` to using Json.NET to generate JSON. In Json.NET, for a UTC `DateTime`, the default datetime serialization was similar to the .NET version:

```
"\/Date(1333645844276)\/"
```

For non-UTC, unlike `JavaScriptSerializer`, Json.NET appends a timezone offset to the results (-6 for my area, this time of year):

```
"\/Date(1333645844276-0600)\/"
```

Here is the code I am using to switch Json.NET 4.5+ back to the `\/Date(...)\/` format (called `MicrosoftDateFormat`):

```
JsonSerializerSettings customJsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() {
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
};
string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now, customJsonSettings);
```

The solution seemed like it would be as simple as telling Json.NET to use a different `DateTimeZoneHandling` setting. I have tried every setting for `DateTimeZoneHandling` (`Local`, `Utc`, `Unspecified`, and `RoundtripKind`) and they all maintain the "-0600" in the output. In fact, they all produce identical results for a non-UTC `DateTime`.

```
JsonSerializerSettings customJsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() {
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
};
string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now, customJsonSettings);
"\/Date(1333647855743-0600)\/"
```

### Caveat

Ideally, I would have all my times in UTC already. I certainly plan to do so with the next version of this API. Since this is a live API, it is not worth risking an output change until a new version is released. It doesn't appear to be an issue for most JSON parsing systems, but I cannot risk the change since the JSON standard doesn't officially say anything about date serialization.

Comment: I have this problem too, exact same problem.

Answer (score 13):

It seems to work just fine for me, see below. My JSON.NET assembly says it's version "4.5.0.0".

```
JsonSerializerSettings customJsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
};
string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now, customJsonSettings);
Console.WriteLine(result); // "\/Date(1344249339881)\/"
```

Perhaps it was a bug that has been fixed?

Explicitly creating a date:

```
var x = new { thedate = new DateTime(2009, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local) };

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x,
    new JsonSerializerSettings() {
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
    }));
// {"thedate":"\/Date(1234652400000+0100)\/"}

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x,
    new JsonSerializerSettings() {
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
        DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
    }));
// {"thedate":"\/Date(1234652400000)\/"}

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x,
    new JsonSerializerSettings() {
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
        DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
    }));
// {"thedate":"\/Date(1234652400000+0100)\/"}
```

Comment: Confirmed. I had the exact same problem. Had JSON.NET 4.5.7, updated to 4.5.8 and now it deserializes datetime correctly.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution to remove timezone offset from `DateTime` for latest version 9.0.0:

```
var time = DateTime.Now;

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(time, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
    DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified
}));

//"{"thedate": "2016-12-15T09:20:00.9375403"};
```

Comment: it should not have been this difficult to find this answer because the others don't strip the offset info.

Comment: The OP is using DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat