# Why timezone is getting appended in property of DateTime

Tags: c#, json, datetime, asp.net-web-api

Below is my DTO.

```
public class CustomerTO
{
  public int Id { get; set;}
  public DateTime? RDate {get;set;}
  public DateTime? LDate {get; set;}     

}
```

When I check in the Database the values for corresponding columns for RDate & LDate are as follows:-

```
RDate = 2017-04-03 21:09:24.273
LDate = 2017-04-03 21:09:24.577
```

My Action.

```
public string Get()
{
   var customers = dal.GetRecords();
   //if I hover the customers object & see the RDate or LDate value it is as desired.

var strJson= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customers);
//but here the value of RDate/LDate has Time zone appended.
}
```

strJson contains  the RDate & LDate values as below.

```
RDate = 2017-04-03T21:09:24.5768697+05:30
LDate = 2017-04-03T21:09:24.5618688+05:30 // why +5:30 timezone is getting appended.
```

**How to address this??**

Any help/suggestion highly appreciated.

Comment: It's there so if the Json is deserialized in another time zone, the original date/time is preserved.

Comment: @stuartd, Sorry I didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `DateTimeZoneHandling` property of the `JsonSerializerSettings` to `Unspecified`:

```
var strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customers, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified
});
```

Comment: But there are other places in my project where no such issue exists. Please add what could be causing this. 
Thanks

Comment: You will need to provide a repo: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Please refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033612/prevent-json-net-4-5-from-appending-timezone-offset-when-using-microsoftdateform